# Selling loot in Ultima 7

Tags: ultima-7

How do I sell things in Ultima 7?

Is there a place where I can sell things like weapons, armor, potions, gems, other stuff?

Answer (score 5):

One of the best methods for getting gold is by selling Silver Serpent venom to the apothecary in Britain.  50 gold per vial and you can find plenty of them in Paws.

Here's a super list of other stuff you can sell:
http://webspace.webring.com/people/xm/melnorme/u7exchng.html

Kessler
Location: Apothecary in Britain
**Item: Silver Serpent Venom**
50 Gold Coins

Willy
Location: Bakery in Britain
**Item: Bread**
5 Gold Coins for 5 Loaves of Bread
Note : Willy is also supposed to buy sacks of flour for 4 Gold Coins each, but for some reason he never accepts them.

Sean
Location: Jewelery Shop in Britain
**Item: Gem**
30 Gold Coins

Cynthia
Location: Mint in Britain
**Item: Gold Nugget**
10 Gold Coins
**Item: Gold Bar**
100 Gold Coins

Brownie
Location: Farm near Britain
**Item: Pumpkin**
1 Gold Coin

Mack
Location: Farm near Britain
**Item: Egg**
1 Gold Coin

Boots
Location: Castle British
**Item: Mutton**
5 Gold Coins

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  Could you add the details of that link to your post?  That way, if the site goes down, the information is still available.  Plus, users won't have to click the link to find the info!

Answer (score 2):

You can sell weapons to the blacksmith and armor to the armorer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: You can sell a few item to special NPC as gems to the juweler, nuggets to the miner. All other loot is not sellable.

Old: <strike>You can't sell loot in Ultima 7.</strike>

Comment: It turns out I can sell gems to the jeweler, gold bars and nuggets to the mint in Britain. I think you're right about not being able to sell other things.

Comment: Yes there limited things you can sell. Afair they are linked to several occupations you can learn to make money; on the other hand stealing is probable the easiest way to make money.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: "All other loot is not sellable." is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you get too much loot, you can place them on the ground. They usually stay there thought out the whole game, except valuables and gold, which disappear after you leave the screen.

The only thing you have to keep are food, keys, reagents, important items and armour.

If you are looking for a quick way to get gold, quickly visit the Buccaneer's den and gamble.

See Advanced Finances - Gambling - 
http://www.it-he.org/ultima7.htm